# Как вставить своё изображение при анимации печати теста?

Tags: javascript, html, css, анимация

Игрался с настройками плагина *typeIt.js* для анимации печати теста, все было хорошо если вставлять смайлы текстом, но *есть ли какой то способ вставить свою картинку(иконку смайлика) при анимации печати теста?* Меня смайлы почти угодили, но есть одно но, в каждом браузере они отображаються по-разному и это ну такоеее.

Вот смайл котика в Apple:

[image: Текст]

А вот в Microsoft:

[image: Текст]

> **ВОПРОС: Как вставить свою иконку при анимации печати плагином typeIt.js и можно это воопше сделать?** Если ответ: "неа", то есть плагин таким функционалом, чтобы смайлы отображались всегда одинаковыми (например Apple) на разных девайсах.

```js
$(function(){
  'use strict';
  new TypeIt(".beauty__typetext", {
     speed: 175,
     deleteSpeed: 70,
     loop: true
  })
     .type("а погладь ", { delay: 300 })
     .delete()
     .type("а попей ☕", { delay: 300 })
     .delete()
     .go();
});
```

```css
// ==> section-beauty <==
.beauty__inner {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.beauty__title {
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #000;
}
.beauty__typetext {
  color: #CEE7BA;
}
// ==X section-beauty X==
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/typeit@7.0.4/dist/typeit.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Section-Beauty -->
<section class="beauty" id="beauty">
  <div class="beauty__inner">
     <h6 class="beauty__title title">
        Не сиди допоздна, <span class="beauty__typetext"></span>
     </h6>
  </div>
</section>
<!-- Section-Beauty END! -->
```

*Документация скрипта typeIt*: https://typeitjs.com/docs

Comment: добавь ссылку на документацию по библиотеке

Comment: в type ты можешь передавать html разметку, а следовательно можешь добавить любую иконку

Comment: @Grundy, Можно примерчик кода, я что то пытался, но у меня не получилось(

Comment: Добавил ответ с примером

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В передаваемых [опциях](https://typeitjs.com/docs#options) есть свойство `html`, по умолчанию оно равно `true`. Следовательно передавать можно не только обычную строку, но и html разметку.

Например:

вместо иконки используем span с фоновой картинкой. При первом запуске, картинка может не успеть загрузиться, но это в принципе решаемо размером картинки, и предварительной загрузкой.

```js
$(function() {
  'use strict';

  new TypeIt(".beauty__typetext", {
      speed: 175,
      deleteSpeed: 70,
      loop: true
    })
    .type("а погладь <span class='cat'>&nbsp;</span>", {
      delay: 3000
    })
    .delete()
    .go();
});
```

```css
.beauty__inner {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.beauty__title {
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #000;
}

.beauty__typetext {
  color: #CEE7BA;
}

.cat {
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url('https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/240/apple/237/cat_1f408.png');
  background-size: cover;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/typeit@7.0.4/dist/typeit.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Section-Beauty -->
<section class="beauty" id="beauty">
  <div class="beauty__inner">
    <h6 class="beauty__title title">
      Не сиди допоздна, <span class="beauty__typetext"></span>
    </h6>
  </div>
</section>
<!-- Section-Beauty END! -->
```

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ :) галочку поставил